# How to ignore 8.3 filename for "move" command in batchscript?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, move, short-filenames

I have to move a lot of xml-Files, named as follow:

- F010199004524001_904.XML
- F010199805946001_737.XML
- F010199904725001_611.XML
- F030390114543001_901.XML
- F030390114544001_257.XML
- F030390114545001_901.XML

in my batch-file, there's this line:

move C:\source\F01*.xml C:\target\F01\

Now I have the problem, that some of the files have a different 8.3-filename, for example

"F030390114545001_901.XML" has the name "F01FCF~1.XML" so this file is also moved in the directory "F01".

The command "fsutil 8dot3name strip" in my case is useless, because the batch is running on a 2003 server.

Is there any type of workaround or alternative commands to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a:-d "c:\source"^| findstr /i /b "F01"^|findstr /i /e ".xml"') do (
   move "%%~fa" "C:\target\F01\"
)
```

this?

**EDIT**

`findstr` filtering can be done with a single expression -

```
findstr /beri "f01.*xml"
```

so

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a:-d "c:\source"^| findstr /beri "f01.*xml"') do (
   move "%%~fa" "C:\target\F01\"
)
```

Comment: I would explicitly match the extension dot using `findstr /xri "f01.*\.xml"`